# Chartjs plugin zoom Reference error: window is not defined

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2, chartjs-plugin-zoom

In Nextjs application while I'm run the command for build and export there was an ReferenceError

I've attached the screenshot for your reference..

When remove the import of chartjs-plugin-zoom from the project, the build and export works properly..
[image]

Comment: Follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75811323/7211502).

Answer (score 1):

This is because nextjs by default use server-side rendering. And zoom-plugin requires `window` object, but it is not available since the component is rendered on a node.

To make work component which relies on browser API , `next/dynamic` import can be used

**chart-with-zoom.jsx**

```
import zoomPlugin from 'chartjs-plugin-zoom'; // require window in order to be imported

ChartJS.register(zoomPlugin)

export default function ChartZoom() {
...
```

**app.jsx**

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const ChartZoom = dynamic(() => import('PATH TO chart-with-zoom'), {
  ssr: false, // Disable server-side rendering
});

...
return <ChartZoom />
```

Comment: import zoomPlugin from 'chartjs-plugin-zoom'; 
Doesn't give a component so importing it dynamically not work and for some reason "use client" is also not working

Comment: Yeah, i was wrong - use client not working, because nextjs still tries to preload component with ssr by default. But importing with dynamic worked for me

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution to this problem after putting my brains. Here it goes

Suppose you are importing the "chartjs-plugin-zoom" in page.tsx then move all the code to a component name lets call ComponentA.tsx and then import this component in page.tsx dynamically and also wrap it with a NoSSR component. Example code
**Page.tsx**

```
   "use client";
import React from "react";
import NoSSR from "./components/NoSSR";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const ComponentA = dynamic(() => import("./components/ComponentA"), {
    ssr: true,
});

const Page = () => {
    return (
        <NoSSR>
            <ComponentA />
        </NoSSR>
    );
};

export default Page;
```

**NoSSR.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";

const useEnhancedEffect =
    typeof window !== "undefined" ? React.useLayoutEffect : React.useEffect;

type Props = {
    defer?: boolean;
    fallback?: JSX.Element;
    children: React.ReactNode;
};
/**
 * NoSSR purposely removes components from the subject of Server Side Rendering (SSR).
 *
 * This component can be useful in a variety of situations:
 * - Escape hatch for broken dependencies not supporting SSR.
 * - Improve the time-to-first paint on the client by only rendering above the fold.
 * - Reduce the rendering time on the server.
 * - Under too heavy server load, you can turn on service degradation.
 */
function NoSSR(props: Props) {
    const { children, defer = false, fallback = null } = props;
    const [mountedState, setMountedState] = React.useState(false);

    useEnhancedEffect(() => {
        if (!defer) {
            setMountedState(true);
        }
    }, [defer]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (defer) {
            setMountedState(true);
        }
    }, [defer]);

    // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-no-useless-fragment
    return <>{mountedState ? children : fallback}</>;
}

export default NoSSR;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to slightly modify the solution from `skorphil`.
If you try to register the zoom plugin outside the component you will still get the same error. That's why you need to do it inside the component as following:

```
useEffect(() => {
if (typeof window !== "undefined")
  import("chartjs-plugin-zoom").then((plugin) => {
    ChartJS.register(plugin.default);
  });
}, []);
```

This makes sure that the plugin code will not run in the server.